# git shows difference between dev and master even directly after merge of dev into master

Tags: git, github

This is happening to me in 2 separate repo's.

My dev branch is ahead of my master branch by several commits. I open a pull request to merge dev into master (squash and merge). After merging, when I compare dev and master again, it shows the same exact diff list of commits.

Opening up another pull request again shows the same commit.

I have resolved the issue by deleting dev entirely and creating a new branch with `checkout -b` when on master, but can someone explain why this occured?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub's "Squash and merge" is not a conventional merge - a brand new commit is created, and then fast-forward merged onto the target branch.  Thus the two branches will appear to be unrelated in the commit graph, so a subsequent diff will show a confusing result.

So S&M is generally only a good idea when the source branch is ephemeral - i.e. if it's not needed once the PR is done.  So it generally makes sense for short-lived feature branches, but not for your use case.

Comment: ah, so after the squash and merge, the history diverges, is that right?

is the general practice to rebase and merge? so all commits on dev that are considered 'passing' would just be copied to master?

Comment: @nxmohamad - Yes essentially the histories of the two branches diverge.  I'm not sure whether R&M would work better - generally I'd advocate a conventional merge for this use case, as the relationship between the two branches will be explicit in the commit graph.